# How to use Docker to run this specific program from Github?

Tags: python, git, docker, github, pytorch

I am working on a project that requires me to recreate the results of a paper. The code used by the authors, along with instructions on how to recreate the results, is here:
https://github.com/ElementAI/N-BEATS/tree/04f56c4ca4c144071b94089f7195b1dd606072b0#datasets

The authors suggest using **Docker**, which I have never used before.

**Here is a summary of what I've tried:**

I downloaded Docker and Python, and ran the following in the command prompt (at the suggestion of a redditor):

`git clone https://github.com/ElementAI/N-BEATS.git`

`cd N-BEATS`

`docker build .`

After running `docker build .` I receieved the following error:

```
[2/9] RUN apt-get update -y --fix-missing && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends software-properties-common wget curl unrar unzip libnvinfer6=6.0.1-1+cuda10.2 libnvinfer-dev=6.0.1-1+cuda10.2 libnvinfer-plugin6=6.0.1-1+cuda10.2 git && apt-get clean -y: 5 1.325 Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB] 5 1.334 Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease [242 kB] 5 1.351 Ign:3 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64 InRelease 5 1.424 Ign:4 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64 InRelease 5 1.440 Get:5 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64 Release [697 B] 5 1.458 Get:6 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64 Release [564 B] 5 1.473 Get:7 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64 Release.gpg [836 B] 5 1.497 Get:8 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64 Release.gpg [833 B] 5 1.691 Ign:9 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64 Packages 5 1.705 Get:9 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64 Packages [334 kB] 5 1.791 Get:10 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64 Packages [49.5 kB] 5 1.843 Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB] 5 2.019 Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB] 5 2.197 Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted amd64 Packages [13.5 kB] 5 2.210 Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages [1344 kB] 5 3.957 Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse amd64 Packages [186 kB] 5 4.195 Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages [11.3 MB] 5 20.05 Reading package lists... 5 20.69 E: Release file for http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 12h 5min 13s). Updates for this repository will not be applied. 5 20.69 E: Release file for http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 12h 5min 52s). Updates for this repository will not be applied. 5 20.69 E: Release file for http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 12h 6min 37s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.

failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to build LLB: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update -y --fix-missing && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends software-properties-common wget curl unrar unzip libnvinfer6=6.0.1-1+cuda10.2 libnvinfer-dev=6.0.1-1+cuda10.2 libnvinfer-plugin6=6.0.1-1+cuda10.2 git && apt-get clean -y]: runc did not terminate sucessfully
```

**My OS:** Windows 10 Home

A few people from Reddit have tried to help me with this problem, but I think the problem is that they weren't following the authors' instructions on the readme.

Comment: Please note that while StackOverflow is for asking for help you should not offer payment.  I have submitted an edit request to remove that specific line.

Comment: the project uses make file, so I would assume that the authors were running it on linux, so this might be the reason.
have you tried running it in windows subsystem for linux?
they have added gpu passthrough so it should be ok
https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2020/06/17/gpu-accelerated-ml-training-inside-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux/

Comment: The error is `E: Release file for http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 12h 5min 13s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.` That suggests the problem doesn't have anything to do with Docker. If you're certain your local clock is correct, I guess try again in 12 hours?